# How to remove underscore in foreign key names generated by Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations

I have a relationship using Entity Framework 4.1 and my foreign key's is generated automatically, the names of foreign key have underscore:

```
public class Setor : Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Secretaria Secretaria { get; set; }
}

public class Secretaria : Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

This generated foreign key named: **Secretaria_Id** in table **Setor**

I want to remove this underscore: **SecretariaId**

Is there a way to do this? I prefer using DataAnnotations.

Comment: Check this link you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329369/multiple-foreign-keys-to-same-primary-key-table/19442004#19442004

it might help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Fluent API you can give the FK columns a name:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Setor>()
    .HasOptional(s => s.Secretaria)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(a => a.MapKey("SecretariaId"));
```

I think this is not possible with DataAnnotations. Alternatively you can expose the foreign key into your model class, like so:

```
public class Setor : Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public long? SecretariaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Secretaria Secretaria { get; set; }
}
```

Conventions will recognize this automatically as the FK and the column name will be the name of the property, i.e. `SecretariaId`.

Comment: using data annotations you can also use the [Column("ColumnName")] attribute to do it with out the fluent api if you are not using a property in your model for your foreign key however you will likely be stuck with using fluent tho

Comment: @Chris McGrath: Unfortunately it doesn't work. You cannot put the `[Column]` attribute on a navigation property. It is simply ignored. It only works in scalar properties.

Comment: ya with navigations you would have to use fluent (which i have personal preference for as its more flexible and cleaner than attributes in you pocos )

Comment: ps you dont need inherit from Entity anymore as of ef 4.0

Comment: @Chris McGrath: I think `Entity` is some custom type here. It's not `EntityObject` which is the base class you probably mean.