# Multiple foreign keys to same primary key table

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table with multiple fields that are foreign keys to a primary key in another table.  For example :

```
Fixture Id (PK)
HomeTeamId (FK to Team.TeamId)
AwayTeamId (FK to Team.TeamId)
HomeTeamCoachId (FK to Coach.CoachId)
AwayTeamCoachId (FK to Coach.CoachId)
```

Would it be better to separate this data into 2 tables HomeTeam and AwayTeam with a foreign key to FixtureId?  This is currently what was generated by Entity Framework :

```
FixtureId PK
HomeTeamId int
AwayTeamId int
HomeTeamCoachId int
AwayTeamCoachId int
AwayTeam_TeamId FK
HomeTeam_TeamId FK
AwayTeamCoach_CoachId FK
HomeTeamCoach_CoachId FK
```

This was generated through this class :

```
public partial class Fixture
{
    public int FixtureId { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int AwayCoachId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Coach AwayCoach { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int HomeCoachId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Coach HomeCoach { get; set; }
}
```

Can anybody tell me if this is the correct way to do this?

EDIT : In reply to Slauma

So my classes would basically look like this?  Or does the configuration in OnModelCreating mean I don't need some of the foreign key related code in my Fixture class?

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Entity Type Configuration
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeamConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CoachConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FixtureConfiguration());

        modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
            .HasRequired(f => f.AwayTeam)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.AwayTeamId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
            .HasRequired(f => f.HomeTeam)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.HomeTeamId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
            .HasRequired(f => f.AwayCoach)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.AwayCoachId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
            .HasRequired(f => f.HomeCoach)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.HomeCoachId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

public partial class Fixture
{
    public int FixtureId { get; set; }
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public byte Week { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int AwayCoachId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Coach AwayCoach { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int HomeCoachId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Coach HomeCoach { get; set; }

    public byte AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    public byte HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with having multiple FK references to the same table (e.g. `Team`) - that's totally OK.

Comment: Technically no problem. Logically maybe. I assume that teams and coaches are related, so a home team cannot just have _any_ home coach. You may want to model a TeamCoach table (FK's to Team and Coach) and have `TeamCoach` references in `Fixture` in stead of `Team` and `Coach` separately.

Comment: Team and Coach are related but a team's coach can change, so using TeamId to get the Coach wouldn't always work out as this table will hold historical data where a team probably would go through several different coaches.

Comment: You can have multiple team-coach combinations (even with history) and select two of these for a fixture. I can imagine you already have a table like this otherwise how are you going to check that the right combinations are made?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently EF doesn't detect your `int` properties like `AwayTeamId` as the foreign key for the navigation properties like `AwayTeam` because the primary key property in `Team` is not `Id` but `TeamId`. It would probably detect the FKs if they are named like `AwayTeamTeamId` or if the primary key property in `Team` has the name `Id`.

If you don't want to change those property names according to EF convention you can define the FKs with data annotations:

```
[ForeignKey("AwayTeam")]
public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

// the same for the other three FKs
```

Or Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
    .HasRequired(f => f.AwayTeam)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.AwayTeamId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

// the same for the other three FKs
```

I have disabled cascading delete because it will be enabled by default for a required relationship. But because you have two required relationships to the `Team` table (and the `Coach` table as well) it would result in two cascading delete paths from `Fixture` to `Team` and `Coach`. Multiple cascading delete paths are forbidden in SQL Server, so you must disable cascading delete for at least one of the two relationships between `Fixture` and `Team` (and between `Fixture` and `Coach`).

Comment: Thanks for the great post, please see my edit to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out this way & working

Primary key Table

```
public class TravelCity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string CityDesc { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Table Having Foreign Key

```
  public class TravelDetails
    {
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 TravelId { get; set; }

    public Int32 FromLocation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FromLocation"),InverseProperty("CityId")]
    public virtual TravelCity TravelCityFrom { get; set; }

    public Int32 ToLocation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ToLocation"), InverseProperty("CityId")]
    public virtual TravelCity TravelCityTo { get; set; }


    public Int32 CurrentCity { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ToLocation"), InverseProperty("CityId")]
    public virtual TravelCity TravelCityCurrent{ get; set; }

}
```

Try out this way it will surly work..
Cheers:)