# Entity Framework: Poor Database Design and Multiple Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing a new version of our software in C# using entity framework. I am new to this technology, but the new version is coming along swimmingly. Our major holdback has been with how to design entities that match our existing (poorly designed) database schema. Designing a new database schema is outside of the scope of this project, although we can make small changes where necessary.

I am currently trying to get around a particular problem that has arisen. Here are some models to demonstrate the problem:

```
public class EntityA
{
    [Key] 
    public int SurrogateKey { get; set; } 
    public int NaturalKey1 { get; set; }
    public int NaturalKey2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EntityB> B { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityC> C { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityBID{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityA "), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int EntityANaturalKey1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityA "), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EntityANaturalKey2 { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityA A { get; set; }
}

public class EntityC
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityCID{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityA ")]
    public int EntityASurrogateKey  { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityA A { get; set; }
}
```

So in our database, we have like 20 entities that follow EntityB, where they reference the natural key of EntityA, and a similar number of entities like EntityC, where they reference the surrogate key.

From what I can tell, entity framework will not allow you to define multiple keys for the same entity. When I try and deal with these models in my application, I get errors regarding Multiplicity and the number of dependent and principal roles not being identical.

Are there are any workarounds to deal with this via Entity framework, or am I going to have to adjust my database such that all entities will use the surrogate key?

Comment: Not 100% sure but i believe your going to need some modification.
Try [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455444/multiple-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-table)... similar thread

Comment: If you have the opportunity to create references to surrogate keys, don't think twice. The great advantage it that they're immutable. Natural keys can (and often do) change because they have business meaning.

Comment: I guess you are going DataBase first with EDMX model? If you use Fluent API you can set composite keys. Here's a walk through on how to reverse engineer DB to fluent API classes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx